# Is there a smart way to allow a program to change IPTable without giving it cap_net_admin capabilities?

Tags: security, ubuntu-16.04, iptables

I want to use Istio's envoy proxy (load balancer) along my kubernetes env, but I have one small problem with it. The init container in Istio  requires cap_net_admin privileges to install IPtables rules.

Is there a smart way I can redirect a program's iptable installation request - one that I do not want to have root access - to one that does have root access that can do it for the non-root program?